# How can I add virtual Python interpreter to VS code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, vagrant, python-venv

- I tried

  in User settings

  {"python.pythonPath": "/home/vagrant/venv/bin/python"}

  - Operating environment

  PC: MacBookPro　
  OS: High sierra
  VM: Virtual Box (vagrant)
  guest OS：ubuntu16.04
  Python3: 3.6.4

When I select python interpreter, new one dosen't displayed.

Comment: Did you reload the editor?

Comment: Yes, I reloaded.

Comment: Did you open the command palette and type python in the search bar?  One of the options to appear is; python: select interpreter. This allow you to select, from a list, one of the available interpreters on your machine. It should show you each virtual environment you've defined.

Comment: @SasakiYuka, Did you find any solution for your question? I am also having same issue, can you please suggest me the answer?

Comment: @jmh, I have added my vagrant file path as mentioned, but it is not showing in the add interpreter dropdown..